# Eclipse, no web project in wizard

Tags: eclipse

Trying to import some code I wrote in intelliJ and I came across a problem on my main workstation, my Eclipse Juno has no option to create a new web project, however on my laptop Eclipse Juno in there has the option, which is odd because it's the same version of Eclipse, any thoughts on how I should be able to start a web project?

**Edit** Thanks Andre, yeah I have the wrong Eclipse but I have so much in my workspace it isn't viable to reinstall it, also getting it to work on Ubuntu was a bit of a pain; I was looking for a single repositry for the EE web tools, thanks.

Comment: Are they the same downloaded file?

Comment: You need the Eclipse WTP plugin for eclipse to support web projects. Make sure it is installed. The update site would be http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno and you find the packages in the category Web, XML, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Andre for the answer, you can find the WTP plugin in the marketplace, unfortunately Juno does not have Marketplace as default therefore you must use  [Juno software repository URL](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno) in the install new software section of Eclipse to download and install the Marketplace